# Passing html form input values in python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have a html form input and basically I want to take the value that I input and pass it into my app.route(/sometext/inputvalue)

```
 @app.route('/inputvalue')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the form request by the app, by using `POST` `GET` methods. so for that you need a login method.
something like this.

```
# you don't need to redirect the template
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['Email'] # suppose you have a email and password field
        passe = request.form['passw']

        return redirect(url_for('index', inputvalue=user)) # then you can pass email or pass
```

and after these things are done and the servers are running, open your html file 
and fill the form. you can see the redirected values by,

```
@app.route('/inputvalue')
def index(inputvalue):
  return ('hey' + inputvalue)
```